# Google Pubsub - Get dequeue count information

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I using Google Pub-Sub service with 1 subscriber and 1 publisher. The code is written with C#. The publisher inserting messages to the "queue" and the subscriber running the background code to handle it.

From time to time I found that my code has a bug that leading me to retry the same message again and again. The problem is that the result is the same for those cases - crash.

My idea to have an attribute of "dequeue-count" that counter how many producers already tried to solve this specific task. If this number is bigger then 3 - drop this message.

Is this possible to get the dequeue count without implementing it manually? (manually = store the message ID in crashes database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google pub-sub service now has a [dead letter queue](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics) feature that can help alleviate this situation.  Muuuuuch better than having to track it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No, Cloud Pub/Sub does not provide a count of the number of times any given message was delivered. You will need to count it yourself.